# Syntax for grabbing the currently selected file

Tags: android, java-io

I was hoping someone could help me with this. Im using java.io.file to specify a file to be uploaded to a server.My question is, how can I change my path to utilize the currently selected file instead of having to hard code a path and file name? The basics of my process is like this -- User long presses on a file in my layout, an upload context menu appears, the user clicks upload and the file is sent to the server. Im just unclear on how to grab the file the user long clicked on in lieu of hard coding the path and filename into the method. Everything I have read on io.file shows a hard coded example. I would really appreciate any guidance given!! You can see what I mean here:

```
                File file = new File("/path/to/file.txt"); //Need to not have to hard code path and filename

                inputStream = new FileInputStream(file); 

                Entry newEntry = mDBApi.putFile("/testing.txt", inputStream,
                        file.length(), null, null);
```

Comment: Just a little more info....The files that are being clicked on are in a DataListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the proper variable in my code to use. It should be

```
 File file = new File(mFileMag.getCurrentDir() + "/" + item);
```